# Retain last character in string with R

Tags: string, r, substring, trim

How can I obtain the last character of each string of various lengths?

```
[1] "3575742" "35752" "3541" ....
```

This would allow to drop the last character but how to retain/extract the character?

```
strtrim(df, nchar(df)-1)
```

So I would get only:

```
[1] "2" "2" "1"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you should look at `substr` instead:

```
substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x))
# [1] "2" "2" "1"
```

This is essentially, "Start at the last character and end at the last character".

or...

```
substring(x, nchar(x))
# [1] "2" "2" "1"
```

---

There's also a great package called [**"stringi"**](http://www.rexamine.com/resources/stringi/) that has a lot of convenient string functions. For this problem, you can use `stri_sub`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_sub(x, -1)
# [1] "2" "2" "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with regular expressions:

```
x <- c("3575742", "35752", "3541")
sub("^.*(.)$", "\\1", x)
# [1] "2" "2" "1"
```